# Almost sure convergence of individual summands

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_i$ and $Y_i$ be random variables. Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n + Y_n = \bar X$ with probability one and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n = 0$ with probability one.

Is it then true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n = \bar{X}$ with probability one?

I think it does but I want to make sure. I know it does if $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are real numbers but I'm not so sure if they are random variables. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is true. $ {\displaystyle X_{n}\ {\xrightarrow {\overset {}{\text{a.s.}}}}\ X} and {\displaystyle Y_{n}\ {\xrightarrow {\overset {}{\text{a.s.}}}}\ Y}, then {\displaystyle aX_{n}+bY_{n}\ {\xrightarrow {\overset {}{\text{a.s.}}}}\ aX+bY} $.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.